# Is it possible to not show background of an image using imageview

Tags: android

Is it possible to hide background of any image as I want to display an image using ImageView and image having white background so I want that that white background should not be display in my application.

Comment: you need to create the image as a .png file with a transparent background

Comment: The only way to do it with ImageView is to create a class that extends it and inside it write a method that decreases the alpha channel of a pixel to 0 if the RGB value of pixel is as follows (255,255,255)

Comment: this is not a way to down vote my question..so what if my question is at low level...

Comment: please someone vote my question..i haven't no more right to ask question.. as i'd already 2 reputations only...

Comment: Why do you need android for that? With `Photoshop` and `Gimp` you can easily make a picture transparent!